# IOS : Glitch after rotate screen with CollectionView image cell

Tags: ios, rotation, collectionview

I'm handling rotate collectionview layout.
everything is fine except one thing:
that imageview in celldon't display good after rotate, i have to scroll left / right for cell (imageview inside it) update.

Here's screenshot.

glitch at bottom of each image cell
[image]

normal view (after scroll left / right)

[image]

How can i avoid this glitch

Answer (score 0):

Try to reload the collection view & set the cell in rotation view.

Comment: reloaddata worked, i tried it. but i'm afraid of memory leak, because i'm doing infinity collectionview scroll that's means it could be alot of images and cells. any better solution for it.